# Docker --cpus use cpu cores or processors to limit usage?

Tags: docker, cgroups

Docker have *--cpus* to constrain CPU usage for container.

According to [docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#configure-the-default-cfs-scheduler), it will

> Specify how much of the available CPU resources a container can use. For instance, if the host machine has two CPUs and you set --cpus="1.5", the container is guaranteed at most one and a half of the CPUs.

However, I run machine:

```
# cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "cpu cores" | tail -n 1
8
# cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "processor" | wc -l
16
```

Does it make sense to set --cpus=8 if I want to set 50% limit to container? Or it will be 100%?

I don't see clear answer neither in Docker documentation nor in cgroups manual.

I saw detailed explanation of differences between physical cpu and virtual cpu and cores [here](http://www.daniloaz.com/en/differences-between-physical-cpu-vs-logical-cpu-vs-core-vs-thread-vs-socket/), but it don't clarify what I should use for my limits with Docker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the process in the container is run with no CPU restrictions and can use all available processor time, competing with other processes running on the Linux host. When setting `--cpus` this configures the cgroup settings to limit processes inside that container to only use that many shares of CPU time. This is managed by the kernel, but the underlying hardware is still visible in `/proc/cpuinfo`. Instead you should look at the cgroup settings:

```
$ docker run -it --rm --cpus 0.75 busybox sh
/proc # cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/cpu.cfs_quota_us
75000
/proc # cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/cpu.cfs_period_us
100000
```

Contrast with an unlimited container:

```
$ docker run -it --rm busybox sh
/ # cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/cpu.cfs_quota_us
-1
/ # cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/cpu.cfs_period_us
100000
/ #
```

Comment: Please clarify: in busybox example 0.75 was for cpu cores or processors? On my hardware with 8 cpu cores and 16 processors what actual restriction will be? 9.375% or 4.6875% of entire  CPU?

Comment: @Kai it's limiting the number of concurrent threads. In your example that's limiting to N/16. The question is more of a Linux one than a docker one since docker is just setting the CFS quota and period values for the container's cgroup.

Comment: Thanks, this comment finally answers my question.